# apply map partitions on pyspark dataframe to run python logic

Tags: pyspark

I would like to apply spacy nlp on my pyspark dataframe. I am using map partitions concept on my pyspark dataframe to apply python logic that consists of spacy.

Spark version: 3.2.0

**Below is the sample pyspark dataframe:**

```
    token                    id
0   [This, is, java, world]   0
1   [This, is, spark, world]  1
```

Below is the code where I am passing a data to the python function and returning a dictionary

```
def get_spacy_doc_parallel_map_func(partitionData):
        import spacy
        from tqdm import tqdm
        import pandas as pd
        nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
        nlp.tokenizer=nlp.tokenizer.tokens_from_list
        from spacy.tokens import Doc
        if not Doc.has_extension("text_id"):
            Doc.set_extension("text_id", default=None)
        
        columnNames = broadcasted_source_columns.value
        partitionData = pd.DataFrame(partitionData, columns=columnNames)
        '''
        This function creates a mapper of review id and review spacy.doc.Doc type
        '''
        def get_spacy_doc_parallel(data):
            text_tuples = []
            dodo = data[['token','id']].drop_duplicates(['id'])
            for _,i in dodo.iterrows():
                text_tuples.append((i['token'],{'text_id':i['id']}))
            doc_tuples = nlp.pipe(text_tuples, as_tuples=True,n_process=8,disable=['tagger','parser','ner'])
            docsf = []
            for doc, context in tqdm(doc_tuples,total=len(text_tuples)):
                doc._.text_id = context["text_id"]
                docsf.append(doc)
            vv={}
            for doc in docsf:
                vv[doc._.text_id] = doc
            return vv
        
        id_spacy_doc_mapper = get_spacy_doc_parallel(partitionData)
        partitionData['spacy_doc'] = id_spacy_doc_mapper
        partitionData.reset_index(inplace=True)
        partitionData_dict = partitionData.to_dict("index")
        result = []
        for key in partitionData_dict:
            result.append(partitionData_dict[key])
        return iter(result)
    
    resultDF_tokens = data.rdd.mapPartitions(get_spacy_doc_parallel_map_func)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(resultDF_tokens)
```

The issue I am getting here is that the length of dictionary values does not match with length of the dataframe. Below is the error

**Error**:

```
ValueError: Length of values (954) does not match length of index (1438)
```

**Output**:

```
{0: This is java word, 1: This is spark world }
```

The above dictionary is assigned as a column to the python dataframe after applying spacy (partitionData['spacy_doc'] = id_spacy_doc_mapper)

Comment: post expected output and spark version

Comment: spark version: 3.2.0 and output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough experience with spacy to figure out what the intent is here and I'm very confused by the input and output because the input looks tokenized, but I'll take a stab at it and list my assumptions and the problems I ran into.

First off, I think [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) can make this type of transformation significantly easier. It will use the underlying Spark UDF, pandas_udf, mapPartition, or mapInPandas depending what parameters you supply. The point is that Fugue will handle that boilerplate. For you, it seems you have Pandas DataFrame in (that part is clear), but the output is less clear. I think you are passing some iterable of list to make Spark happy, but I think Pandas DataFrame output might be simpler. I'm guessing here.

So first we set some stuff up. This is all native Python. The `tokens_from_list` portion was removed from the original because it seems like the latest versions deprecated it. Shouldn't matter for the example.

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import List, Any, Iterable, Dict

import spacy
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy.tokens import Doc
if not Doc.has_extension("text_id"):
    Doc.set_extension("text_id", default=None)
    
data = pd.DataFrame({"token": ["This is java world", "This is spark world"],
                   "id": [0, 1]})
```

and then you define your logic for one partition. I am assuming Pandas DataFrame in and Pandas DataFrame out, but Fugue can actually support many other types such as Pandas DataFrame in and Iterable[List] out. The important thing is just you annotate your logic so Fugue knows how to handle it. Note this code is still native Python. I edited the logic a bit to just get it to work. Again, I am pretty sure I butchered the logic somewhere, but the example can still work. I really couldn't find a way for the original to work (because I don't know spacy enough)

```py
def get_spacy_doc(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    text_tuples = []
    dodo = data[['token','id']].drop_duplicates(['id'])
    for _,i in dodo.iterrows():
        text_tuples.append((i['token'],{'text_id':i['id']}))
    doc_tuples = nlp.pipe(text_tuples, as_tuples=True,n_process=1,disable=['tagger','parser','ner'])

    docsf = []
    for doc, context in doc_tuples:
        doc._.text_id = context["text_id"]
        docsf.append(doc)
        
    vv={}
    for doc in docsf:
        vv[doc._.text_id] = doc
    
    id_spacy_doc_mapper = vv.copy()
    data['space_doc'] = id_spacy_doc_mapper
    return data
```

Now to bring this to Spark, all you have to do with Fugue is:

```py
from fugue import transform
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data)
sdf = transform(sdf, get_spacy_doc, schema="*, space_doc:int", engine=spark)
sdf.show()
```

and the Fugue transform will handle it. This is to run on Spark, but you can also run on Pandas if you don't supply an engine like this:

```py
df = transform(data, get_spacy_doc, schema="*, space_doc:int")
```

This allows you to test the logic clearly without relying on Spark. It will then work when you bring it to Spark. Schema is a requirement because it is a requirement for Spark.

**On partitioning**

The Fugue transform can take partitioning strategy. For example:

```py
transform(df, func, schema="*", partition={"by":"col1"}, engine=spark)
```

but for this case, I don't think you partition on anything so you can just use the default partitions, which is what will happen.

**On parallelization**

You have this code like:

```py
nlp.pipe(text_tuples, as_tuples=True,n_process=8,disable=['tagger','parser','ner'])
```

This is two-stage parallelism. The first stage is Spark mapping over partitions, and the second stage is this pipe operation (I assume). Two stage parallelism is an anti-pattern in distributed computing because the first stage will already occupy all the available resources on the cluster. The parallelism should be done on the partition level. If you do something like this, it's very common to run into resource deadlocks when the 2nd stage tries to occupy resources also. I would recommend setting the `n_process=1`.

**On tqdm**

I may be wrong on this one but I don't think tqdm plays well with Spark because I don't think you can get a real time progress bar for work that happens on worker machines. It can only work on the driver machine. The workers don't send logs to the driver for the functions it runs.

If the example is clearer, I can certainly help you port this logic to Spark. Feel free to reach out. I hope at least some bit of this was useful.

Comment: thanks a lot for you detailed analysis. your example is clear. Can you port this logic to spark?

Comment: If you mean using native Spark, I think it's a lot easier to just stick with spaCy rather than learn Spark NLP. You already have the logic defined. I think you can bring the logic as a UDF. It depends on the Schema. This Fugue ransform function is an easier interface for the UDF, but my concern is what you are attempting to return. If you are trying to return some spacy class that is not a native Java type, I am unsure you can return it directly. The workaround though is to pickle it and use "binary" in the schema. And then you can unpickle it in downstream operations. Does that answer you?